# Add typewrite effect to an onclick event that is already changing div content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an effect called typewrite that I am applying to any text in div `#bubble` so I just wrote it like this:

```
$('#bubble').typewrite({'delay': 35});
```

It works just fine. Now I also have a link with an `onclick` event to change the content of `#bubble` as follows:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#bubble').html('New content');return false;">Change</a>
```

The problem is the link does not do the typewrite effect when it shows the new content. It shows the new text, but without the effect. How do I apply the effect to the new content as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reattach typewrite to `#bubble`

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#bubble').html('New content').typewrite({'delay': 35});return false;">Change</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. I had actually tried the opposite. i.e. putting the typewrite first.